# Data Updating only with beak point, without changing code. in winform using c#?

Tags: c#

I have problem in refreshing data in a Windows Forms application. I have one server (it is also an other client) and one client. My task is to update data in list by clicking on button and server side client is updating properly, but in client it is not updating for the first time.

But by keeping debug point on particular point it is updating on client side also. I understood that this is happening because of Timing issue, so I used `Thread.Sleep();`.
But still I am facing the same problem.
I am not able to understand why this is happening without changing any code.

Comment: How can we help without seeing your code?

Comment: are you waiting for the data? cannot help you without understand how you are doing it

Answer (score 1):

Do not ever -EVER- use `Thread.Sleep();` This is just something you do when you're trying out stuff but has pretty much no use in production.

That being said, you're experiencing a race condition, which are usually annoying to debug because they depend on server-client communications.

I suggest you take a look at async-await, if you haven't already, and you set your code so you wait (await) for the server to give you the update before updating your UI.

If you're already using async/await I suggest you show us some code so we can at least help you out a little. But with the information currently available, I suggest you look this up and learn a bit from there. It'll help a lot